# google app store datastore data in static file

Tags: java, javascript, python, html, google-app-engine

So here is what I want to do. I want to have a static HTML and javascript file in Google App Engine (by the way, I can write it in either Java or Python). So I want the user to visit my `index.html` file and get information from the datastore, but how would I do this?

I understand you must access the datastore from Java or Python, but once I get the data using these languages, how do I make it appear on my`index.html` page (preferably without refreshing). I have tried to find this information everywhere, but all I can find is how to access the datastore using the two languages, not how to take that data and put it into my HTML page.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python or Java app runs on the server, while any Javascript functionality you have is run on the client (in the web browser). [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) is generally the best way to communicate between the two.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Yes, this is what I thought I would have to do. Unfortunately, I tried to find a tutorial on how to do this, but was unsuccessful.

Comment: GIYF. Try [this one](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/rpc) to start out...

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, sorry I cant vote for you all!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you had access data from datastore and you would like to show it on index.jsp .
Suppose your data is greeting with property "user" and "content" . then you can write like this in your jsp file.

```
if (greetings.isEmpty()) {
%>
<p>Guestbook '<%= guestbookName %>' has no messages.</p>
<%
} else {
%>
<p>Messages in Guestbook '<%= guestbookName %>'.</p>
<%
for (Entity greeting : greetings) {
   if (greeting.getProperty("user") == null) {
%>
   <p>An anonymous person wrote:</p>
<% 
} else {
%>
<p><b><%= ((User) greeting.getProperty("user")).getNickname()
%></b> wrote:</p>
<%
}
%>
    <blockquote><%= greeting.getProperty("content") %></blockquote>
<%
}
}
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GqlQuery](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlqueryclass) to get the data as a python object. Use [GqlEncoder](https://gist.github.com/mentat/1334268) to convert from GQL to JSON.
self.response.write() the data to a url.
Then, with javascript, you can make an [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest) to get the data from that url, and include the javascript into the html.

A stackoverflow question/answer on the [XHR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15270604/1126809) doing a similar task.